# Sequelize include query with correct limits?

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I have such query

```
    const companiesByEmployeesOfProdUnits = await models.CompanyProductionUnitNonCeased
                    .findAll({
                        raw: true,
                        limit: 5,
                        offset: 0,
                        attributes: [[sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', sequelize.col('company_id')), 'company_id']],
                        include: [{
                            model: models.ProductionUnitCore,
                            as: 'production_unit',
                            include: [{
                                model: models.EmployeeInformationProductUnit,
                                as: 'employee_information_product_units',
                                attributes: ['number_of_employees'],
                                where: { is_current: true, ...rangeOfEmployees }
                            }]
                        }]
                    })
```

There are more then 2 million records. How can I get 5 records? Because now I have only one but I'm sure about correct where conditions and I don't understand why I get only one instead of 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need only to add 'required: true' field for each 'include' object